# How to split a seach term by ":"

Tags: regex, ruby

I have the following search term:

`"login:17639 email:fakemail@gmail.com ref:co-10000 common_name:testingdomain organization:'Internet Company'"`

This term is derived from a params variable where everything to the left of the `:` is a filter term and everything on the right of `:` is the value of the filter. What I'm trying to do is to split the term into keys and values and create a hash from them. This is the end goal:

```
search_filters = {
  login:17639,
  email:'fakemail@gmail.com',
  etc, etc,
}
```

I'm playing around with `split, gsub, tr` to get these values but I'm having a problem with the organization field. Here is what I have so far:

```
term.gsub(/'/,'').tr(':', ' ').split(" ")
term.gsub(":")
```

And basically, many other variations like the above. The problem is the organization field. Every iteration results in something like this `["organization", "Internet", "Company"]` the problem is that "Internet Company" is being split. I can't place a simple if/else statement just for this filter to glue them together because there are more filters to process. Is there a way I can simply divide the filter term based off the colon easier? Thank you.

Comment: I modified my answer. Incidentally, were you notified by SO that my answer had been edited?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example on how to start:

```
def splart(input)
  input.scan(/([^:]+):('[^']*'|"[^"]*"|\S+)/).to_h
end
```

That will tease out the data you need. You may have to clean it up after.

Comment: This returns `{ "login"=>"17639", " email"=>"fakemail@gmail.com",... }`. By "clean it up after" I presume tadman is referring to the need to convert `"17639"` to an integer and to remove some leading spaces, such as the space preceding `"email"`, both of which are straightforward.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That regex could use some tuning to help with that, but also strip off the quotes it manages.

Comment: ...and also the keys need to be converted to symbols.

Answer (score 4):

```
str = "login:17639 email:fakemail@gmail.com ref:co-10000 " + 
      "common_name:testingdomain organization:'ABC Internet Company'"
```

```
Hash[*str.split(/:| +(?![^'":]+['"])/)].transform_keys(&:to_sym)
  #=> {:login=>"17639", :email=>"fakemail@gmail.com",
  #    :ref=>"co-10000", :common_name=>"testingdomain",
  #    :organization=>"'ABC Internet Company'"}
```

See [Hash::[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) and [Hash#transform_keys](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys).

We can document the regular expression by writing it in *free-spacing* mode:

```
/
:         # match :
|         # or
[ ]+      # match > 0 spaces
(?!       # begin negative lookahead
  [^'":]+ # match > 0 chars other than ', " or :
  ['"]    # match ' or "
)         # end negative lookahead
/x        # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

In free-spacing mode spaces are removed before the expression is parsed. That is why spaces intended to be part of the regex must be protected. I've done that by enclose a space in a character class (`[ ]`) but one could instead escape a space character, use Unicode's `[[:space:]]` or `\p{Space}` or, if appropriate, `\s`, which would include tabs and newlines (and a few more characters).

Suppose `str` were shorter and contained only two key-value pairs, and we computed:

```
arr = str.split(/:| +(?![^'":]+['"])/)
  #=> ["login", "17639", "email", "fakemail@gmail.com"]
```

We would use `Hash::[]` as follows:

```
Hash["login", "17639", "email", "fakemail@gmail.com"]
  #=> {"login"=>"17639", "email"=>"fakemail@gmail.com"}
```

which is the same as:

```
Hash[*arr]
```